# Stacking and dynamic programing

Tags: dynamic-programming, combinatorics, knapsack-problem

Basically I'm trying to solve this problem :

**Given N unit cube blocks, find the smaller number of piles to make in order to use all the blocks. A pile is either a cube or a pyramid. For example two valid piles are the cube 4 *4 *4=64 using 64 blocks, and the pyramid 1²+2²+3²+4²=30 using 30 blocks.**

However, I can't find the right angle to approach it. I feel like it's similar to the knapsack problem, but yet, couldn't find an implementation.

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are the items to pack two-dimensional squares or cubes? Please be more specific on how the input looks like and how it relates to the desired output.

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the lack of precision, they are cubes.
A example would be :
To stock 38 blocks we only need two piles: e.g., one cube of height 2 (holding 8 blocks) and a pyramid of height 4 (holding 30blocks).

Comment: According to [this](http://hub.hku.hk/handle/10722/152229) publication, it is already NP-hard to decide whether a set of squares can be packed into a square; I would guess that the same holds for the problem in the question.

Comment: I think there has been some misunderstanding - are all items if the input of the same size, namely of side length 1?

Comment: Yes they are indeed all of length 1.

Comment: Ok I see; so the problem is to distribute `N` unit cubes to the minimum number of piles such that the number of unit cubes in each pile is either a square number or a triangle number?

Comment: Exactly ! You got it right.

Answer (score 0):

First I will give a recurrence relation which will permit to solve the problem recursively. Given `N`, let

```
SQUARE-NUMS
TRIANGLE-NUMS
```

be the subset of square numbers and triangle numbers in `{1,...,N}` respectively. Let `PERMITTED_SIZES` be the union of these. Note that, as `1` occurs in `PERMITTED_SIZES`, any instance is feasible and yields a nonnegative optimum.

The follwing function in pseudocode will solve the problem in the question recursively.

```
int MinimumNumberOfPiles(int N)
{
    int Result = 1 + min { MinimumNumberOfPiles(N-i) }
    where i in PERMITTED_SIZES and i smaller than N;
    return Result;
}
```

The idea is to choose a permitted bin size for the items, remove these items (which makes the problem instance smaller) and solve recursively for the smaller instances. To use dynamic programming in order to circumvent multiple evaluation of the same subproblem, one would use a one-dimensional state space, namely an array `A[N]` where `A[i]` is the minimum number of piles needed for `i` unit blocks. Using this state space, the problem can be solved iteratively as follows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if i is 0 set A[i] to 0,
    if i occurs in PERMITTED_SIZES, set A[i] to 1,
    set A[i] to positive infinity otherwise;
}
```

This initializes the states which are known beforehand and correspond to the base cases in the above recursion. Next, the missing states are filled using the following loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
{
    if (A[i] is positive infinity)
    {
        A[i] = 1 + min { A[i-j] : j is in PERMITTED_SIZES and j is smaller than i }
    }
}
```

The desired optimal value will be found in `A[N]`. Note that this algorithm only calculates the minimum number of piles, but not the piles themselves; if a suitable partition is needed, it has to be found either by backtracking or by maintaining additional auxiliary data structures.

In total, provided that `PERMITTED_SIZES` is known, the problem can be solved in `O(N^2)` steps, as `PERMITTED_SIZES` contains at most `N` values.

The problem can be seen as an adaptation of the [Rod Cutting Problem](https://hayestech.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/dynamic-programming-rod-cutting/) where each square or triangle size has value `0` and every other size has value `1`, and the objective is to minimize the total value.

In total, an additional computation cost is necessary to generate `PERMITTED_SIZES` from the input.

More precisely, the corresponding choice of piles, once `A` is filled, can be generated using backtracking as follows.

```
int i = N; // i is the total amount still to be distributed
while ( i > 0 )
{
    choose j such that
    j is in PERMITTED_SIZES and j is smaller than i
    and
    A[i] = 1 + A[i-j] is minimized
    Output "Take a set of size" + j; // or just output j, which is the set size

   // the part above can be commented as "let's find out how
   // the value in A[i] was generated"

   set i = i-j; // decrease amount to distribute
}
```

Comment: For instance, what would be the idea to do the backtracking to find the piles of the optimal partition ?